# Do any actual bitcoin credit / debit cards exist yet?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card, debitcard

With the rumors of the Bitinstant credit card failing to deliver, and the only other one out there being a fake scam site, does *anyone* out there offer a solution to this?

Just the ability to pay with Bitcoin wherever credit cards are accepted in USD is all I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bitcurex offers prepaid cards for Euro, Dollar, Pounds and PLNs](http://shop.bitcurex.com/index.php).

Comment: I love the professional nature of their sales - "*You can always pretend that this card is an new feature of BTC: “You just have to load the BTC to it and voilà, the system converts it to an appropriate currency and you are able to pay with BTC :D”, Imagine all these chick on the vacation that you will have to explain to."

Comment: @RichardGreen Yeah, bothers me too.

Comment: BitPay, Shift, and XAPO all offer these cards now. BitPay converts bitcoins to dollars when you reload. Shift pulls bitcoins as needed from your Coinbase account. XAPO pulls from their own bitcoin wallet.